# Programmatically select cell in datagridview based on it's value

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I'm populating a dataGridview in my winforms application using a list of strings (single unnamed column), however I need a way to select a single sell by it's value in order to change the text color.

How can I do this?

this is how I'm populating it:

```
List<String> companyNames = new List<String>();

//.. other logic that fills up companyNames

companyDataGridView.DataSource = this.companyNames.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
```

After which I need to somehow select the cell, based on the value it gets from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be pretty, but I ended up throwing this together.. and it seems to work.

```
private DataGridViewCell GetDataGridViewCellByValue(String value, DataGridView dataGridView)
        {
            List<DataGridViewCell> myCells = new List<DataGridViewCell>();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow myRow in dataGridView.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell myCell in myRow.Cells)
                {
                    myCells.Add(myCell);
                }
            }

            DataGridViewCell returnCell = myCells.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.ToString() == value);
            if (returnCell != null)
            {
                return returnCell;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Then simply using this below I can get the desired cell:

```
DataGridViewCell testCell = this.GetDataGridViewCellByValue("Company1", this.companyDataGridView);
            if (testCell != null)
            {
                testCell.Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an eval in the html, this means that you can call the server side function in each row and determine its colour.

Luckily I have already used this recently and here is an example:

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Level Achieved">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblActual" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Actual") %>' BackColor='<%# GetLevelColour(Eval("Target"),Eval("Actual"))%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAchievedLevel" runat="server">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here you can see that the backcolour of the cell is determined by what is returned from the function GetLevelColour, I also pass in two parameters that are used in the function.

This may or may not be the sort of function you require, however my interpretation of the question was how to change colour of a cell when its value is equal to a predetermined value (in this case a word of length 2 as the length was output to the cell instead of the string).

I dont know much about Winforms, however I gave it a shot. Whilst I couldn't get the list to bind strings, I could pull the value out and compare against a known value. Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "2")
                {
                //To colour the row
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

                //To select the row
                row.Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault, It's not a website but a winform application, so I need to access it "behind the scenes"

Answer (score 0):

This could be a scalable and fast solution :

```
Dictionary<string, Color> valuesForColors = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.FormattedValue != null && valuesForColors.ContainsKey(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = e.CellStyle.SelectionForeColor = valuesForColors[e.FormattedValue.ToString()];
}
```